# Unseting element from non associative array without setting a key for each element

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having a little issue.

I have a nested array where I want to delete one object from the middle. I tried unsetting but that gives each element a key which i don't want (as i want to make an easy to navigate json array from it)

For a better understanding an example:

This is a part of my array (contacts is not the only element, but this way it is easier to see):

```
{
   "contacts": [
       {
       "name": "1234",
       "displayname": "1234",
       "groups": [
           "1234",
           "1234456"
       ]
       }
   ]
}
```

And i want to delete an entry from the contacts array. 
My current function is as follows:

```
foreach($responseArray['contacts'] as $key => $contact){
        if($contact['name'] == $_POST['username']){
            unset($responseArray['contacts'][$key]);
        }
}
```

Which kinda works, but makes the contacts array into an json object which i don't want (it gives every entry a key '1' : first contact, '2': second contact .....)

like so:

```
{
   "contacts": {    
       "1": {   
             "name": "1234",  
             "displayname": "1234",  
             "groups": [  
                       "1234",  
                       "1234456"  
             ]  
            }  
   }  
}
```

Any way of doing it without without unsetting the whole contacts array and resetting it with all but the one object?

Comment: I'm confused. You said "this is my array" followed by a json object. Then you said that your foreach makes it into a json object despite the fact that there is nothing in that code which would do that.

Comment: "contacts" first contains an array [...], while it contains an object {...} after I deleted the element using unset. (json_encode implicit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a requirement in JSON that's set by the underlying JavaScript language. JS does not support "sparse" arrays, and always assumes that a `[...]` array definition string will have consecutive array keys. e.g.

```
var foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
      keys: 0    1    2
```

You can't have (for instance)

```
var foo = [0 => 'a', 10 => 'b', 20 => 'c'];
     keys: 0         10         20
```

As soon as you unset a value from the "middle" of your array, your keys go non-consecutive, and JSON is forced to use an object to hold the data.

Comment: Hm, okay, thanks... So my only chance is to rebuild the entire array, which might get quite slow in larger arrays. But thank you nontheless.

Comment: @Daepilin If you use `array_values($arr)` you can basically reset the zero-indexed array so the keys are sequential. Documenatation: http://php.net/array_values